# Facing error in magento 2 : Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I've been facing the invalid form key, error in Magento 2.4. I've tried all the steps produced in the other mutually asked questions, already increased the

```
max_input_vars = 15000 
memory_limit = 2048M
max_input_time = 600 & max_execution_time = 3600.
```

but still, I'm facing the same problem. it would be really appreciated if someone will answer or solve this.

Comment: Hello Vishal, can you let me know where you facing issue, in frontend or in backend and what operation you are doing that could help me to sort your issue.

Comment: Hi, Jayram I'm facing this issue on backend, i used a theme Known as Electro 2 from themeforest. And after I uploaded about 300 products on my site I'm facing this issue, in one of the theme's option from backend. The page, refresh and take me to the user dashboard

Comment: Hi Vishal where you adding these values, in .user.ini file ? and check your nextwork post request and check the size of post and let me know